# Spring Security - LDAP Authentication and DB Authorization

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, ldap, spring-security-ldap

In my SpringBoot application, I want to authenticate my user again Enterprise AD and then Authorize (Grant Authorities) from an application-specific database table.
Eg: User A authenticated from LDAP and then from DB to get the roles for user A.

I am able to set up LDAP authentication and created a custom UserRepository to fetch the user information and role from the database. But, I am not able to figure out how to plug the two together and get the roles of the authenticated LDAP user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you provide a [LdapAuthoritiesPopulator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.15.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/LdapAuthoritiesPopulator.html) bean such as the [UserDetailsServiceLdapAuthoritiesPopulator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.15.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/UserDetailsServiceLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.html) and implement your user details service you should be able to set the roles.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to successfully implemented this.

Comment: @PanwarS87 could you share working example ?